# Create a rolling array from an array of arrays with es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a data set which is like such.

```
this.data = [[opens, opens, opens, etc],
  [closes, closes, closes, etc],
  [highs, highs, highs, etc],
  [lows, lows, lows, etc]]
```

I have a function that is grabbing the first item of each array and returning a single array like

`[opens, closes, highs, lows]`

I need the function to actually create a rolling window so its like

```
[opens, closes, highs, lows],
[opens, closes, highs, lows], 
[opens, closes, highs, lows],
[opens, closes, highs, lows], 
[opens, closes, highs, lows],
```

For this example lets say I wanted the last 4 as well as the current one.

The function is using a reduce. What syntax do I need to replace reduce with?

```
const candle = this.data.reduce(
    (array, item) => [...array, item[index]],
    []
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do this way if you still wanted to use `reduce()`:

```js
const data = [
  ["opens", "opens", "opens"],
  ["closes", "closes", "closes"],
  ["highs", "highs", "highs"],
  ["lows", "lows", "lows"]
];

let res = data.reduce((acc, list, idx, arr) =>
{
    if (idx >= list.length)
        return acc;

    return [...acc, arr.map(x => x[idx])];
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: How is it returning a new array with only the size of list.length? How does it know to create that size of new array?

Comment: First, is this what you wanted, because I was not sure, there are other answer that may accomplish your goal. It basically stops to change the `accumulated` parameter of the reduce when the `index` of the current `list` related to `data` array is greater or equal than the `list` length: `if (idx >= list.length) return acc;`

Comment: Also if this data.reduce is sitting inside a .forEach like such. How can I make sure that each for each its returning the proper sliding window?


`this.opens.forEach((x, index) => {
      let res = this.networkInput.reduce((acc, list, idx, arr) =>
      {
          if (idx >= 5)
              return acc;

          return [...acc, arr.map(x => x[idx])];
      }, []);
      console.log("res", res)
});`

Comment: Sorry dude, I can't get into your real context. I suggest to made a new question with an explanation (including sample data and expected output) of what you really need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610886/foreach-and-reduce-to-create-a-rolling-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 1):

You could rotate the data first and then take a subset.

```js
var data = [['opens0', 'opens1', 'opens2', 'opens3', 'opens4', 'opens5'], ['closes0', 'closes1', 'closes2', 'closes3', 'closes4', 'closes5'], ['highs0', 'highs1', 'highs2', 'highs3', 'highs4', 'highs5'], ['lows0', 'lows1', 'lows2', 'lows3', 'lows4', 'lows5']],
    rotated = data.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []);
    
console.log(rotated);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want a *nested* array result, you need to iterate over the subarrays first, rather than over the outer `.data` array. I'd use two `.map`s:

```js
const data = [['opens', 'opens', 'opens'],
  ['closes', 'closes', 'closes'],
  ['highs', 'highs', 'highs'],
  ['lows', 'lows', 'lows']];
const candles = data[0].map((_, i) => data.map(subarr => subarr[i]));
console.log(candles);
```